# UITableView won't reload contentSize

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview, reload

I have a UITableView, that add's some data after the UITableView reloaded for the first time, but I can't scroll down to the new data if I scroll I see the new data but then it scrolls back automatically, and yes I reloaded my UITableView, so I checked my UITableView contentSize and it won't change after the reload but after I go to another view (UINavigationController) and pop back the UITableView contentSize does change and it works! How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: paste ur code too.. :)

Comment: I'm guessing that either your `– numberOfRowsInSection:` or `– numberOfSections` is not being correctly updated. Hard to say without some code though...

Comment: They are correct, but I already fixed it by using insertIndexPaths:

Comment: @DaanLemmen Please state the reason for the issue and your fix as an answer. You answer may help another person. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it using the same technique as Daan (as far as I can tell).

In my case I was using a static UITableView that had some of its rows and sections hidden initially (by setting appropriate return values from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`). I was pushing a VC onto the nav stack to collect additional data which I would then use to fill in the hidden tableview sections, calling reloadData on the tableview to refresh it.

This worked fine in iOS7, but in iOS6 the tableview's `contentSize.height` never changed from its initial value (218 pts) to the taller value (504 pts) derived from the addition of the new sections. As such, you could not scroll to the content at the bottom of the tableview. Trying to force the contentSize did not work as it was immediately set back to 218.

Changing the tableView's `contentOffset` allowed me to scroll to the bottom of the content, but if you tapped the UITextField in the last cell, it would whip off screen as the keyboard was shown.

I finally was able to come up with a solution that worked in both iOS6 and iOS7 without issue. I used the old `beginUpdates` / insert or delete rows and sections / `endUpdates` methods of UITableView, as follows:

```
// change the tableView's data source to reflect insertions/deletions
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSRangeFromString(@"1,3")] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

As you can see, in this particular case I had to remove a row from the first (and only) section and add three sections to the end of the tableview.