# UITableView scroll content size incorrect after dismissing another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

So I have a `UITableViewController` which launches another `tableVC` which changes the number of cells for the original when dismissed.

Upon dismissal, despite returning the correct cell height (and header height) as well as updated number of rows (such that the scroll content is huge), the scroll view only bounces when scrolled. Upon looking at the `contentSize` property of the scroll of the table, the `contentSize` is incorrect and is the same as it was previously.

When initially loading the original `tableVC`, I do not have the problem. If I have a large number of cells, the table will scroll as expected. It is only upon dismissal of the presented `tableVC` that I run into the problem. One thing I am unsure of is when to call reloadData. I am doing it as follows:

1. in presented `tableVC`:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

2. in original tableVC:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear    
{ 
   //tablecell number manipulated
   [table reloadData];

}
```

The funny thing is if I rotate to landscape and back to portrait, the contentSize is then set correctly and I can scroll again.

Comment: Just came across this, is `viewDidAppear` a typo - have you not copied the code correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Add a

```
[table setNeedsDisplay];
```

Also, is there a particular reason why you are not animating?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I also tried setNeedsLayout along the same line of thinking.

Comment: How about adding back the animation?

Comment: It is actually animated in my real code, I just made a mistake here. I need it to be animated.

Comment: is this a timing related issue when does contentSize get calculated for scrollviews in tables?

Comment: I am having the same issue and I have a animation block in which I set table setNeedsDisplay but nothing happens. How did you fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369449/uitableview-inside-a-navigation-controller-does-not-scroll-after-dismissing-pres

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by explicitly reloading the section and not using the reloadData.
[table reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was changing the number of rows and sections of a static tableView in response to data entered in a child viewController, but while the content was updating, the `contentSize` was not, leading to scrolling problems.

In my case there seems to be a bug in `reloadData` in iOS6 which prevented the tableView from properly calculating the new size (this worked fine in iOS7). I solved this by calling the appropriate inserts and deletes on rows and sections, as detailed here: [UITableView won't reload contentSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443388/tableview-wont-reload-contentsize/19624088#19624088).